# ZF2 - How to get the url and the parameters in the view

Tags: zend-framework, view, routes, zend-framework2

I would like to know how I can make to get the url and the parameters in the view.

This code get the Controler name without the pamameters...

```
<?php echo $this->url();  ?>
```

Thanks you for your helping.
Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Use following to get get url with parameter

```
$this->url('route', array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action', 'paramkey'=>'value'), array('force_canonical' => true))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get them easily from view script. You can however get them in Controller and pass it to view.

For simple paramaters you can use: `$this->view->params = $this->getAllParams()`

If you need something more, you need to ask Request object for it. To get Request object: `$this->view->request = $this->getRequest()`. From now you can get all info from view by using eg. `$this->request->getRequestUri()`

Remember that you can use `var_dump(get_class_methods($this->request))` to get list of all available methods.

Answer (score 2):

A very late response in case it could help someone.

You can get request params in the view using :

```
$routeMatch = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()

$params = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
```